# Does telnet add any extra bytes when sending data?

Tags: c, sockets

I am sending a command from telnet and receiving it using my own server using socket command recv(). If I send "aa", the bytes received are 4. I can understand that the 3rd byte is \n but what is the 4th byte?

Code:

```
        int r = recv(my_socket_fd, message, max_buffer, 0); //r=4 when input is aa
                if(r>0) 
                    message[r]='\0'
```

Comment: telnet *terminal emulator* can send different terminal control sequences.

Comment: Google for "telnet IAC" :: http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/node141.html

Comment: The ascii sequence for aa is 97,97,13,10

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am sending a command from telnet and receiving it using my own server using socket command recv(). If I send "aa", the bytes received are 4. I can understand that the 3rd byte is \n but what is the 4th byte?

The "network virtual terminal" implemented by Telnet defines these among its control sequences (character codes in decimal):

```
     Line Feed (LF)         10      Moves the printer to the
                                    next print line, keeping the
                                    same horizontal position.
     Carriage Return (CR)   13      Moves the printer to the left
                                    margin of the current line.
```

([RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854))

Note well that in order to move the output position to the beginning of the next line, a two-character sequence is required.  Conventionally, that is CR LF, but in principle it could also be LF CR (but Telnet requires that a CR not followed by LF be followed by NUL).  The upshot of this, and of the fact that the telnet protocol is symmetric, is that the Telnet on-the-wire line terminator is the two-character sequence CR LF.  This is what you are observing.